# How not to let the call convert %20 to a space between words

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

To send a message to Telegram, I use this template:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

urlphoto = f'http://127.0.0.1:0001/Home/Site%20de%20Trabalho%20-%20Home.html'
botalert = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
chatalert = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
urlalert = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botalert + "/sendMessage?text=" + urlphoto + "&chat_id=" + chatalert + "&parse_mode=HTML"
requests.get(urlalert, headers=headers)
```

But when the message is sent, the link received there does not come together as the `%20` is converted into spaces:

[image]

How should I proceed so that the link is delivered perfectly like that:

```
http://127.0.0.1:0001/Home/Site%20de%20Trabalho%20-%20Home.html
```

Comment: if this is your site then stop using spaces in URLs - it will always makes only problems.

Comment: if it converts `%20` to `spac`e then maybe try `%%20` and maybe it will convert it to `%20`

Comment: Hi @furas This is very true, unfortunately in this case I won't be able to change and now I've found myself with this problem on my hands!

Comment: if I use `urllib.parse.quote(' ')` then it converts it to `%20` and if I use `urllib.parse.quote('%20')` then it converts it to `%2520` - so maybe you should use `%2520` in place of `%20` and it will `unquote` code `%2520`  to `%20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameters dictionary, and the parameters will be encoded correctly for you:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

urlphoto = f'http://127.0.0.1:0001/Home/Site%20de%20Trabalho%20-%20Home.html'
botalert = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
chatalert = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
urlalert = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{botalert}/sendMessage'
params = {'text':urlphoto, 'chat_id':chatalert, 'parse_mode':'HTML'}
requests.get(urlalert, headers=headers, params=params)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define urlphoto like this:

```py
urlphoto = f'http://127.0.0.1:0001/Home/Site%20de%20Trabalho%20-%20Home.html'.replace('%20', '%2520')
```

This will print the percent sign with 20 after it.

Comment: The right way to do this is not to manually create the parameters, but pass a dictionary of parameters via the `params` parameter.  Then they will be encoded correctly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import requests
from requests.utils import quote

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

urlphoto = 'http://127.0.0.1:0001/Home/Site%20de%20Trabalho%20-%20Home.html'
botalert = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
chatalert = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
urlalert = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{botalert}/sendMessage"
requests.get(urlalert, params=quote(f"?text={urlphoto}&chat_id={chatalert}&parse_mode=HTML"), headers=headers)
```